# How do i open other .dart activity from bottom navigation bar item?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have implemented the following bottom navigation bar with the flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatelessWidget  {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build
return new Scaffold(
    bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.add),
              title: new Text("trends")
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.location_on),
              title: new Text("feed")
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.people),
              title: new Text("community")
          )
        ]
    )
);}}
```

How do I make, `onTap` on each `BottomNavigationBar` item opens new `.dart` class?
I have tried with the `TabBarView` for the tab but have no clue what to do for the bottom navigation bar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  TestState createState() {
    return new TestState();
  }
}

class TestState extends State<Test> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        onTap: (newIndex) => setState((){_currentIndex = newIndex;}),
        items: [
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.add),
              title: new Text("trends")
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.location_on),
              title: new Text("feed")
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.people),
              title: new Text("community")
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: new IndexedStack(
        index: _currentIndex,
        children: <Widget>[
          new YourCustomTrendsWidget(),
          new YourCustomFeedWidget(),
          new YourCustomCommunityWidget(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Working like a charm. :)

Comment: Instead of PageStorageKey this StackedIndex widget is best for persisting the state of an bottomNavItem while using BottomNavBar. Good Job!!

Comment: Hello, imagine that I have a login page that, after being authenticated, presents a bottomnavbar that loads a few pages, identical to its proposed solution. My problem is that within the pages shown by bottomnavbar I have a button for logout and everything I've tried causes the login page to be loaded but with the bottomnavbar together. Any suggestion?

Comment: is their a github example of this?

Comment: @RussellHarrower Maybe this helps: https://github.com/nisrulz/flutter-examples/blob/master/using_bottom_nav_bar/lib/main.dart